# SQL query not loading

Tags: qgis, sql

I did a SQL query from a Geopackage with QGIS database manager. The query is correct and it returns me the expected result with it's ID and the GEOM columns. The problem becomes when I load the query as a layer. The software creates the layer but is void as you can see:

[image]

Parameters and columns;

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: I solved it, the problemas was the amibguity between 2 of the columns in the query, ech one of those were at 2 diferents layers. I just especifyed adding "column.atribute" and then the layer loaded with all the information.

Comment: You should answer your own question when you are able. Might help other people out.

Comment: The SQL query was a CTE. I did the proces in two querys. First I did the a JOIN, and then I did a selection over that JOIN. I don't know why the result of the CTE's (wich it was correct) it loaded as a void layer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problemas was the amibguity between 2 of the columns in the query, ech one of those were at 2 diferents layers. I just especifyed adding "column.atribute" and then the layer loaded with all the information.